# Moodle enrol_manual_enrol_users api error

Tags: php, moodle-api

I have been getting the error below when i try to enroll users to moodle through enrol_manual_enrol_users

Array ( [exception] => invalid_parameter_exception [errorcode] => invalidparameter [message] => Invalid parameter value detected [debuginfo] => enrolments => Invalid parameter value detected: Missing required key in single structure: roleid )

This is my code

```php
$MoodleRest = new MoodleRest('http://localhost/moodle/webservice/rest/server.php', $this->token);
        
$enrolment = array(
    "userid" => $user_id,
    "courseid" => $course_id,
    "roleid" => 4
    );
$enrolments = array(array($enrolment));
$params = array( 'enrolments' => $enrolments );


$result_query = $MoodleRest->request('enrol_manual_enrol_users', $params);
if (!empty($result_query['exception'])) {
    print_r(array('Error querying enroll', $result_query));
    die();
}
```

Comment: Hello, have you tried with 

    `$enrolment= new stdClass(); $enrolment->userid = 101;`  (and so on..) then     `$enrolments = array($enrolment);`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $MoodleRest = new MoodleRest('http://40.81.1.212/moodle/webservice/rest/server.php', $this->token);
    

    $par = array(   //e_s_s 
        'enrolments' =>     array(  //e_m_s
                array(   //e_s_s 
                'userid' =>$user_id ,
                'courseid' =>$course_id , // PARAM_NUMBER   VALUE_REQUIRED[]
                'roleid' =>$role_id //PARAM_RAW VALUE_OPTIONAL  [] ))
            );

        print_r($par);
        echo "<br><br>";
        $result_query = $MoodleRest->request('enrol_manual_enrol_users', $par);
        if (!empty($result_query['exception'])) {
            print_r(array('Error querying enroll', $result_query));
            //die();
        } 

        var_dump($result_query);

    echo '</br>************************** Server Response  EnrollUser()**************************</br></br>';
```